# How to detect whitespace of operator

Tags: java

I have some problem about my code.

I want to detect whitespace of operator like `" + "`, `" +"`, `"+ "` or `"+"`.

I want my output is

- Whitespace of an operator is "A"

How can I modify my code?

My code is here.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (new File(PATH to file));
int plus1;
int plus2;
int plus3;
int plus4;
String sPlus = "";
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    in.hasNextLine();
    LOC++;
    if (line.length() > 0) {

        plus1 = -1;
        plus2 = -1;
        plus3 = -1;
        plus4 = -1;
        while (true) {
            plus1 = line.indexOf(" + ", plus1 + 1);
            plus2 = line.indexOf(" +", plus2 + 1);
            plus3 = line.indexOf("+ ", plus3 + 1);
            plus4 = line.indexOf("+", plus4 + 1);

            if (plus1 > 0) {
                sPlus = "A";
            }
            if (plus2 > 0) {
                sPlus = "B";
            }
            if (plus3 > 0) {
                sPlus = "C";
            }
            if(plus4 > 0){
                sPlus = "D";
            }

            if ((plus1 < 0) || (plus2 < 0) || (plus3 < 0) || (plus4 < 0)) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so what is your input and what is your expected output? Currently, regardless of any of the `plusX` numbers, as long as `plus4 > 0`, you will get `"D"`

Comment: My input is text file like a java code and my expected output is print A, B, C or D

if A is " + "
   B is " +"
   C is "+ "
   D is "+"

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to solve here, you are almost certainly going about it the wrong way. You should be scanning the input a character at a time, ignoring whitespace, and then reacting to whatever character you found. Instead you are repeatedly scanning the same input for different things, which performs poorly and just leads to endless special cases, as you are discovering. This is not how exoressions are evaluated, or how program code is parsed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*if A is " + "*"? I thought A is the value that you wanted to output

Comment: @cricket_007 My expected output is A, B, C or D.

Comment: I mostly understand the output you want, but not the input you are reading in... Do you want to print out a letter for every single `+` operator? If so, I feel like regex would better address your problem than `indexOf` because that only finds the first operator on a line

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I want to print out a letter for every single + like 
if in text file have " a + b" printout "A", "a +b" print out "B", "a+b" print out "D"

Comment: I'm not the best with regex, but [here is a sample](https://regex101.com/r/dW5iZ2/1) of the 4 regex patterns you should look at using.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your logic:

1. You are using `trim()` in `line.indexOf(" +".trim(), plus2+1)`, which returns the index of `"+"` NOT `" +"`
2. Any one occurrence of `" + "` will be counted 4 times, because `line.indexOf(" +")` will also count occurrences of `" + "`

For 2. it would be much easier to use `line.indexOf('+')`, and then check before and after the index to see how many whitespaces there are:

```
int plus = line.indexOf('+');
if(plus == -1) break;
if(line.charAt(plus-1) == ' ') {
    if(line.charAt(plus+1) == ' ') //A;
    else //B;
}

else if(line.charAt(plus+1) == ' ') {
    //C
}

else {
    //D
}
```

Comment: 1. my code is updated.
2. Can I use .trim() of " +" ?
3. Can I break my loop?

Comment: @Anonymous `trim()` removes all leading and trailing whitespace, so no. And breaking your loop depends on what you're trying to do. And sorry I misread your code, your breaking logic is fine.. I thought you were breaking the main loop.

Answer (score -1):

Proper else-if could be help.

```
if (line.indexOf(" + ") != -1) sPlus = "A";
else if (line.indexOf(" +") != -1) sPlus = "B";
else if (line.indexOf("+ ") != -1) sPlus = "C";
else if (line.indexOf("+") != -1) sPlus = "D";
else break;
```

Comment: That's wrong, because it doesn't handle cases where there are more than one occurrence of `+`

Comment: @Maljam I agree to cricket_007. There's no need to handle the case.